# in Xcode 10.1 is there a reason I have to continuously log in to GitHub after restarting my computer?

Tags: ios, xcode, github, ssh, rsa

In Xcode 10.1 I have noticed when I restart my MacBook, every time I go back toward on my Xcode projects, I have to re-enter my GitHub credentials to use source control. I have the RSA saved to my keychain to enable automatic source control via SSH. But after updating to Xcode 10 or 10.1 (I'm not sure which) everytime I try to push to my remote repos, Xcode pops up asking for my credentials.

Answer (score 0):

They seem to have tinkered with the usage of SSH in the github transactions.

Now XCode requires you to register your github user name and password under the "Accounts" preference pane.  Once you have entered it and authenticated with github, XCode produces a dialog allowing you to decide how you wish to clone (ssh or or https) and in the case of ssh, which key you'd like to use.

Once that has been done, it appears to work as before.  I guess the new method is "better" for people starting fresh, but breaks backward compatibility for those of us that have had it working well for a long time.

As we all know, backward compatibility is not high on the list at Apple.